# JPA: ensure that child objects are replaced on update

Tags: java, jpa

There is a persistent class that has a collection of child elements (setters, getters etc. removed from the listing):

```
@Entity
@Table(tableName = "...")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "myEntity")
    private List<DateValue> values;
}
```

The child class is in fact just a tuple of LocalDate and BigDecimal:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity_date_values")
public class DateValue implements Serializable {

    LocalDate date;

    BigDecimal value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")
    MyEntity myEntity;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

The problem is that when a new list of (transient) values are created and set with the setter, new entities are created instead of replacing the existing:

```
List<DateValue> values = someDto.getSomeValues().entrySet().stream()
                    .map(entry -> new DateValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), myEntity))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
MyEntity.setValues(values);
```

What can be done to avoid it and ensure that old values are either updated or replaced by new ones?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the DateValue list (the [...] in your code) ? I'm interested in how do you build your list of values. Do you create new DateValue objects ? And if so, do you assign an id to them ?

Comment: Currently I'm creating the values with a constructor without assigning an ID. One of my ideas is to replace the artificial ID with a compound key of all the three fields and make it really a data class.

Comment: @ElementCollection may be the answer (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/embedded-element-collection.html). I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace @Entity with @Embeddable in the case of DataValue and mark the list in the owning class (MyEntity) as @ElementCollection.

```
@Entity
@Table(tableName = "...")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "my_entity_date_values")
    private List<DateValue> values;
}

@Embeddable
public class DateValue implements Serializable {
    LocalDate date;

    BigDecimal value;
}
```